# Not seeing the Integration section in AWS Eventbridge

Tags: aws-event-bridge

What could be the reason that I am not seeing the AWS Eventbridge Integration section?

I am on the US Gov cloud and I am a systems administrator. When navigating to the Amazon Eventbridge these are the only options I have on Gov Cloud. I have read that Gov cloud does support API destinations.

[image]

But if I navigate to Amazon Eventbridge on my own AWS account which is not gov cloud I see more options like below. The item I am mainly looking for is the API Destinations.

[image]

UPDATE - After checking out what TLeitzbach mentioned -

I see this option on S3 bucket being on gov cloud, which means Eventbridge can receive events from S3 bucket.

[image]

This is what I got from ChatGPT regarding sending events to Salesforce from eventbridge -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation "Setting up partner event sources to receive events from Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) Partner applications and services is not supported."
This also includes API destinations.

See also the [official website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-eventbridge.html) for further differences such as "Amazon API Gateway is not supported as an event bus target."

Comment: Hello TLeitzbach, The Amazon Eventbridge would be only receiving events from the S3 bucket, which is supported and will be sending the payload to Salesforce which is also supported. The issue I am having as per the screenshot above is that I am missing the whole Integration section.

Comment: I understand it this way that partner event sources is not supported and I could not find an explicit statement that API destinations are supported. I guess from the statement on SSL (first bullet point) and you missing the section I inferred that none of the two are supported. Could you point me to the link where you read that API destinations are supported? Does it work via cdk https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.ApiDestination.html on your Account?

Comment: This link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-bidirectional-event-integrations-with-salesforce-and-amazon-eventbridge/  and https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-amazon-s3-event-notifications-with-amazon-eventbridge/

Comment: I did not see any reference to AWS GOV, did I miss it?

Comment: I added some snips to the original post.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see where you are coming from. If you have an AWS support plan this is probably the most reliable way to get a clear answer. To be honest, I still believe that this outbound logic is simply not available on US gov but fingers crossed!

Comment: Did contact them today. They said it is not as of now supported on gov cloud